# jQuery Raty set score inside click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, raty

I'm trying to use [this](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) rating plugin but I was unable to set the new score on click.

I'm making an ajax request on click event and get new calculated score. I wanted to set the new score inside the click event. What is the right way to do it?

```
<div class="rating" data-id="some-int" data-score="0.5"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".rating").raty({
    score: function () { return $(this).attr("data-score"); },
    click: function (score, evt) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "./ajax.asmx/RateImage",
            data: "{ ImgId: " + $(this).attr("data-id") + ", Score: " + score + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) { actionResult = result.d; }
        });

        if (actionResult.Success) {
            console.log("Score: " + actionResult.Message);
            score = actionResult.Message;
        } else { // cancel rating
            alert(actionResult.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why make it synchronous (`async: false`)? Why not an async call? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8kcu8qsr/2/

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle I linked to?

Comment: @abhitalks I don't really know details about async. If set true, actionResult gets undefined. So the code after ajax block continues to run even the result is not completed. And this is not something I want.

Comment: And to know more about AJAX, Async and how to use the return value, please see this canonical QA: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1355315

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. I'll fix my code blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built in method to set new score, so just use:

```
$('.rating').each(function(i) {
    var thisRating = $(this);
    thisRating.raty({
        score: function () {
            return $(this).data('score');
        },
        click: function (score, evt) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: './ajax.asmx/RateImage',
                data: {
                    ImgId: thisRating.data('id'),
                    Score: score
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    thisRating.raty('score', result.d.Message);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Under [docs - Functions](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) you will find:

> $('#star').raty('score');
>
> Get the current score. If there is no score then undefined will be
>   returned.
>
> $('#star').raty('score', number);
>
> Set a score.

Comment: Both $(this).raty("setScore", actionResult.Message); and $(this).raty("score", actionResult.Message); worked, but the problem was selected value is being set after this code line. So I added return false; to prevent further assignments. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
$(".rating").raty('setScore', score);
```

See it working

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdVQyO

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, you can simply do `$('#selector').raty({score: 3})` to set the score. So in the callback, you can call `$(".rating").raty({score: actionResult.Message})` like so:

```
$(".rating").raty({
    score: function () { return $(this).attr("data-score"); },
    click: function (score, evt) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "./ajax.asmx/RateImage",
            data: "{ ImgId: " + $(this).attr("data-id") + ", Score: " + score + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) { actionResult = result.d; }
        });

        if (actionResult.Success) {
            console.log("Score: " + actionResult.Message);
            $(".rating").raty({score: actionResult.Message});
        } else { // cancel rating
            alert(actionResult.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When I use this or $(this).raty({score: actionResult.Message}); the elemen(s) reinitialize. So I can't use this.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy What is the problem with the element reinitializing?

Comment: It looses all the properties and events.